# Javascript switch not working on Ajax-Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I am building code for multiple update records using code [from this link](https://www.webslesson.info/2018/09/update-multiple-rows-with-checkbox-in-php-using-ajax-jquery.html). The purpose is to update multiple files with same id number. So far, the code is working good, but I need some adjustment on the display, so I need to incorporate some switch in the javascript.

Here is my database files:

```
CREATE TABLE `matreq_list` (
`num` int(11) NOT NULL,
`sto` int(11) NOT NULL,
`pn` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
`qty` int(11) NOT NULL,
`stat` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
`remark` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

--
-- Dumping data tabel `matreq_list`
--

INSERT INTO `matreq_list` (`num`, `sto`, `pn`, `qty`, `stat`, `remark`) VALUES
(39, 611111, 'BACB10A155G', 1, 2, ''),
(40, 0, '', 0, 1, ''),
```

Below is my html part for multiple file update:

```
....
<table class="table table-striped my-4 w-100" id="datatable2">
                    <thead>
                       <tr>
                          <th width="3%"></th>
                          <th width="5%">No</th>
                          <th width="15%">STO</th>
                          <th width="20%">PN</th>
                          <th width="8%">Qty</th>
                          <th width="10%">From</th>
                          <th width="10%">Dest</th>
                          <th width="15%">Status</th>
                          <th width="14%">Remark</th>
                       </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody></tbody>
                 </table>
....
```

and below is the javascript part, the one causing my headache:

```
....
<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){  

function fetch_data()
{
    $.ajax({
        url:"multiple_select.php",
        method:"POST",
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(data)
        {
            var html = '';
            for(var count = 0; count < data.length; count++)
            {
                html += '<tr>';
                html += '<td><input type="checkbox" id="'+data[count].num+'" data-num="'+data[count].num+'" data-sto="'+data[count].sto+'" data-pn="'+data[count].pn+'" data-qty="'+data[count].qty+'" data-supplant="'+data[count].supplant+'" data-dest="'+data[count].dest+'" data-stat="'+data[count].stat+'" data-remark="'+data[count].remark+'" class="check_box"  /></td>';
                html += '<td>'+(count+1)+'</td>';
                html += '<td>'+data[count].sto+'</td>';
                html += '<td>'+data[count].pn+'</td>';
                html += '<td>'+data[count].qty+'</td>';
                html += '<td><span class="btn btn-oval btn-primary">'+data[count].supplant+'</span></td>';
                html += '<td><span class="btn btn-oval btn-warning">'+data[count].dest+'</span></td>';

                html += '<td>'+data[count].stat+'</td>';
                html += '<td>'+data[count].remark+'</td></tr>';
            }
            $('tbody').html(html);
        }
    });
}

fetch_data();
```

The one that I need to modify is

> html += ''+data[count].stat+'';

to show text instead of value (1-4). I have tried using switch case as below :

```
var switchstat;
                switch (data[count].stat) {
                    case 1:
                        switchstat = "Process";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        switchstat = "Document";
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        switchstat = "Travel";
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        switchstat = "Final";
                        break;
                    default:
                        switchstat = "Value not Recognized"
                 };
```

I put the **switchstat** to replace **data[count].stat**, however, the value return default on all rows on the table. I tried in a different line and it still shows default even though the data is available in the mySQL. Please advise what should I do to catch the value from mySQL to my script?

Thank you for your kind help and guidance.

Comment: Have you tried using a Template literal?  html += `<td>${data[count].stat}</td>`;  ?

Comment: sorry for my bad English, its been 24 hours nonstop learning and implementation, and I really need to catch some sleep now :P

Comment: Is `data[count].stat` a number or a string? If it is a string your switch will always return the default

Comment: @dsadnick yes i have tried, successfully catch the integer, but I need to switch the value to text. The faster solution is to change the SQL to text type. But it will cause more problem when I need to filter using SQL statement since text usually cannot be used in WHERE SQL syntax..

Comment: @charlietfl it should be number, as stated in my database definition sir.

Comment: Ok but is it sent to browser as number?

Comment: yes it is sir @charlietfl, now my problem already solved in response below :D

Comment: Well if parseInt solved problem then it was a string not number. The difference would be `"2"` vs `2`.....quotes vs no quotes

Comment: yes, i just now understand how json_encode default behaviour are. so even in SQL we define data type into INT, once we fetch to json it will be automatically changed to TEXT if we did not use the numeric check option, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to parse `data[count].stat` into an int for the switch to work properly:

```
switch (parseInt(data[count].stat)) {

...


}
```

Comment: oh my god, thank you for your insight sir! Now my script can work nicely! Thank you so much for your help :D Now i may sleep in peace :D

Comment: out of curiosity, why did parseInt used nicely in this block of code? I assume that when my database already declared the column as INT, it should be handled as is? Could you please help to explain to me as a noob sir? :D

Comment: @OkaMahendra Likely due to using `json_encode()` in php without a numeric check option set and default is to encode to string

Comment: @charlietfl understood, so basically i have alternate solution, either a). use json_encode($data,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK), or b). use the parseInt if numeric check option not set, am I correct?

Comment: Yes ....or use a hashmap object instead of a switch